# Draggable attribute aurelia

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, aurelia

I am trying to create a draggable custom attribute using aurelia and jquery-ui however I always get the following error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

I installed jquery and jquery-ui using aurelia-cli (au install jquery and au install jquery-ui).

Here is my attempt:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';

@inject(Element)
export class UiDraggableCustomAttribute {

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        $(this.element).draggable();
    }
}
```

It seems like jquery-ui is not imported correctly. Can anybody tell me how to use jquery-ui correctly with aurelia?

Comment: We can see you've imported `jquery-ui`, however from the error it has not worked. Check that the paths to the relevant JS files are correct, and they have been loaded successfully.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I checked that jquery-ui is present in the packages.json, aurelia.json and node-modules directory. However I am not sure of how to check that they have been loaded?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, check it in the Sources panel of the developer console

Comment: Can you try `import draggable from "jquery-ui";`?

Comment: Honestly, I recommend loading jQuery and jQuery UI via script tags, or putting them in the `prepend` section of `vendor-bundle` if you're jusing the Aurelia CLI. Then they're available globally (as they were designed to be), and we don't have to resort to shoehorning them in to ES2015 modules and hoping they work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just see my sources in src and app-bundle and vendor-bundle in scripts.

Comment: @thebluefox I tried but the result is the same.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I tried to put jquery and jquery-ui in the prepend section of aurelia.json but I cannot compile anymore. `au build` gives "`File not found or not accessible: ...jquery.js`" for every file or dependency requiring jquery.

Comment: You have to point specifically to the path of the file. You can see an example here: https://github.com/AshleyGrant/standard-aurelia-demo/blob/master/aurelia_project/aurelia.json#L91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this work using jquery-ui version 1.10.5, I could not figure out how to use newer version of the jquery-ui npm package.

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

import 'jquery';
import { draggable } from 'jquery-ui';

@inject(Element)
export class DraggableCustomAttribute {

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        $(this.element).draggable();
    }
}
```